# edit array in mongodb - PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

My data like this:

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 51a6fca3f348aca011000000
        )

    [first_name] => Phan
    [last_name] => Chuong
    [interests] => Array
        (
            [0] => football
            [1] => swimming
            [2] => PHP
            [3] => music
        )

)
```

I want edit value **PHP** to **PHP1** or set **PHP** to **null**. Please help me how can i do it? Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could use the MongoCollection::update() method like this:**

```
// $c is your MongoCollection Object

$updatedata = array('$set' => array("interests.2" => "PHP1"));
$id = new MongoID('51a6fca3f348aca011000000')
$c->update(array("_id" => $id), $updatedata);
```

The update method needs two arrays, the first one will tell the DB which Object to update ( In this example where id = our id, always use the MongoID Object, always!), the second array defines what to update, note that you can get to values in nested arrays wit the dot like above. $set is an Field Update Operator, read more on them here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/

**Or you could just get the entire Array, change it, and save it back.**

```
$cursor = $c findOne("_id",4cb30f560107ae9813000000);
$cursor['interests'][2] = 'whatever';
$c->update($cursor);
```